# I am trying to install PostgreSQL on a Ubuntu subsystem for Windows 10 and keep getting this -bash permission denied

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, permission-denied

I am trying to setup PostgreSQL on the Ubuntu subsystem for Windows 10 and when I try to run the ph_hba.conf file the console gives me:

```
-bash: /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf: Permission denied
```

I tried running with `su` or `sudo` but that didn't help.

Comment: Actually I am trying to open the file, not run it

Comment: What do you mean by "open the file"? What's the exact command you're running?

Comment: which editor do you want to use to edit the file?